# Google Maps v3 in Android webview gives error user denied geolocation

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I am trying to load google map v3 (Javascript) in a web view in android

It always gives error

> user denied geolocation

Written using Ionic , it works fine in desktop chrome(ionic serve), and ios devices , error appears only in android

Git repo : `https://github.com/aishwat/temp`

Already done following:

1. In manifest

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

2. For webview

`webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);`

3. Referred to following links

[google-maps-javascript-geolocation-not-working-on-chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429527/google-maps-javascript-geolocation-not-working-on-chrome)

[html-navigator-user-denied-geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725594/html-navigator-user-denied-geolocation)

and few others

Nothing works plz help

Comment: Follow the instruction on [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066876/cordova-ajax-call-not-working-on-ios-works-fine-on-android/33071460#33071460), it will solve your issue. If not, respond here. I will be traveling in a few minutes and may not respond for 24 hours.

Comment: Is the API key right and what do you see in https://console.developers.google.com/project?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650
I tried

`
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
`

<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">


But still doesn't work, this project doesn't have any dependency on cordova itself , I can remove cordova out of picture completely , still map loads but no geolocation

@Joerg , It works fine if i do ionic run android --device , so not api key issue

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @JesseMonroy650 for help but it did not fix my issue

Finally after a lot of searching i got this [android webview geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329662/android-webview-geolocation/5423026)

So issue was , i was using default web view client rather than chrome client and I had to override this method as mentioned in post `onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt`

Anyways thanks for help man !

Answer (score 0):

@aishwat,
Ionic is using Cordova by default, so I'm not sure how you would do that. I do NOT use Ionic, not yet at least.  I have used v3 of the Google maps with *PhonegapBuild*. I set [my version](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/googleMapExamples) as such in my `config.xml`

```
`<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.5.0" />`
```

You should be able to set your Cordova compiler to some 3.x version. That will at least verify your code on the Android. After that, it should be a `white-list` issue.

FWIW: I looked at your code. YOU DO NOT HAVE the *white-list plugin*. You need ALL three things to use the white-list properly. You need:

1. white-list
2. white-list plugin
3. CSP

Re-read that [last link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066876/cordova-ajax-call-not-working-on-ios-works-fine-on-android/33071460#33071460).

**With the CLI version, if you do not assign a version for your platform (...) (and) If you are not lucky, you'll get a set of cascading errors.**